# MS Access Form: Control default values not being used

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form with several bound textboxes for which I want their values to persist as the user creates subsequent records.  I try to achieve this by setting the control's default value property to its own value in the AfterUpdate event.

Example:

```
Private Sub txtEntryStaff_AfterUpdate()
    txtEntryStaff.DefaultValue = txtEntryStaff
End Sub
```

I am able to confirm the property is being correctly set by checking the value in break mode.
I advance the record with a command button attached to the following code in its Click event:

```
    Me.Recordset.Update
    Me.Recordset.AddNew
```

The first record recorded in the session is correctly updated with all initial values preserved in the underlying table.  Textboxes intended to contain the persistent values for subsequent records, however, display on the form as "#Name?" as if the control is no longer bound.  Entering values in other fields appears to initialize the new record and the "#Name?" goes away, leaving a blank field where there should be a default value.  Values recorded in other non-persistent fields are recorded properly.

**Update**:

**@TheMortiestMorty**: I want the values the user enters into the top textboxes on the form (see screenshot below) to remain the same through every subsequent record the user generates.  The textboxes below those will not have default values and therefore will be entered and unique for every new record.

[image]

**@June7**: Thank you for the reference.  In my search for the answer I came across the same article.  Unfortunately, my code does successfully modify the default value of the textboxes (not the default field value in the table defs).  For some reason the default values do not populate the top textboxes when a new record is created.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "want their values to persist as the user creates subsequent records"?

Comment: Can you add some pictures to show what you want Access to do?

Comment: I edited my original post to hopefully clarify.

Comment: What happens if you use this for your DefaultValue assignment? `Me.txtEntryStaff.DefaultValue = """" & Me.txtEntryStaff.Value & """"`

Comment: @HansUp - My friend, you've done it!  I have to know why this works.  Please submit as an answer!

Comment: Comment to other question (which shows the same solution as HansUp comment) explains why quotes are needed.

Comment: Thanks I was just looking back at that post and completely overlooked the addition of the quotes.  Thanks again, all.  Quoting @AdamTips for completeness: "Note that the extra quotes around a text value are required. Otherwise you will just get #Name? because the default value is expecting an expression, not a text value."